# ruby arrays can each_with_index do steps?

Tags: ruby, parsing, text, ruby-1.9.3

I have a txt file of records:

```
firstname lastname dob ssn status1 status2 status3 status4 firstname lastname dob ...
```

I can get this into an array:

```
tokens[0] = firstname
...
tokens[8] = firstname (of record 2).  
tokens[9] = lastname (of record 2) and so on.
```

I want to iterate over `tokens` array in steps so I can say:

```
record1 = tokens[index] + tokens[index+1] + tokens[index+2] etc.
```

and the step (in the above example 8) would handle the records:

```
record2, record3 etc etc.

step 0 index is 0
step 1 (step set to 8 so index is 8)
etc.
```

I guess I should say these records are coming from a txt file that I called .split on:

```
file = File.open(ARGV[0], 'r')
line = ""
while !file.eof?
   line = file.readline
end
##knowing a set is how many fields, do it over and over again.

tokens = line.split(" ")
```

Comment: Can you reedit your code? also give you java code and expected output,how it looks like in Java. Probably that would be great to answer your fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) you could also assign variables to your fields inside the block:

```
tokens.each_slice(8) { |firstname, lastname, dob, ssn, status1, status2, status3, status4|
  puts "firstname: #{firstname}"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this help?

```
tokens = (1..80).to_a #just an array
tokens.each_slice(8).with_index {|slice, index|p index; p slice}
#0
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
#1
#[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
#...
```